# Difference between CMAccelerometerData and CMDeviceMotion

Tags: ios, accelerometer, core-motion

Can someone explain the difference between `CMAccelerometerData` and `CMDeviceMotion`.

It seems to me like the acceleration values of `CMAccelerometerData` are raw values, as the data of `CMDeviceMotion` is somehow interpolated, or something like that.

Comment: For anyone interested, I found the best explanation in this post:
[The Art Of Core Motion in iOS](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/07/the-art-of-core-motion-in-ios/?lang=en)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An instance of the CMAccelerometerData class represents an accelerometer event. It is a measurement of acceleration along the three spatial axes at a moment of time.

An instance of CMDeviceMotion encapsulates measurements of the attitude, rotation rate, and acceleration of a device.

The difference is that `CMDeviceMotion` incorporates the gyroscope, accelerometer and compass data where `CMAccelerometerData` only contains the raw accelerometer data.

Answer (score 8):

These are the differences between `CMAccelerometerData` and `cmdevicemotion`.

1. Raw accelerometer data is the sum of all accelerations measured i.e. a combination of gravity and current acceleration of the device.
2. Device motion data is the result of sensor fusion of all 3 sensors i.e. accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. Thus bias and errors are eliminated (in theory) and the remaining acceleration data is separated into gravity and acceleration to be used conveniently.

In order to compare both you gotta check `CMAccelerometerData.acceleration` against `CMDeviceMotion.userAcceleration` + `CMDeviceMotion.gravity` to compare like with like.

In general `CMDeviceMotion` is your first choice in most cases when you want precise values and hardware independency.